# Have to reconnect microphone every time I reboot

Tags: usb, sound, microphone

Using a Blue Yeti USB microphone, connected to a Dell dock, connected to a laptop on `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS`.

The external mic is set as the default through a startup script (`pactl set-default-source alsa_input.usb-Generic_Blue_Microphones_LT_2007170933195F390975_111000-00.analog-stereo`), and it is correctly identified whenever I reboot.

The problem is that even though the mic is listed there and selected, it does not actually receive any input unless I disconnect and reconnect the usb/power cable in the microphone.

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

--

Edit:

Turns out I have the same problem when connected to my Windows desktop, so it's probably hardware and not Ubuntu at all.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, here is a theory at least:

It may happen that some kernel module needed for this is not loaded properly at boot time, but it gets loaded when you plugin the device later on. To see if this happens, you could run the `lsmod` command (or `dmesg` or other such tools) after boot and then again after replugging the mic cable. If you see a difference in the list of modules, that could give a clue to what is missing. (Then the next step would then be to figure out how to ensure the needed module gets loaded at boot time.)

You might ask, why then would the mic be listed and selected, if needed kernel modules are missing? Just speculating, but it could be that the existence of the mic is one thing, but for it to function properly something more is needed, that "something" could be a kernel module.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and, in my case, ``lsmod`` returned exactly the same list of modules before and after replugging the mic on startup unfortunately.